# Python / Windows: Wait for process to be started

Tags: python, windows, events, windows-7

I'm writing a Python program on Windows 7. I want the program to patiently wait for a process to be started that has a certain name, and then do an action after it was started.

I can easily write the program using polling, i.e. checking every second whether the process is active, but I want to be more efficient and wait on the system event that is generated when a process is started. Is that possible in Python?

Comment: Not sure it's possible in Windows not a python specific question

Comment: If you control the process you're waiting for, you can have it do something on startup and wait for it in the other process, e.g., connect to socket.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If Procmon can listen to events, I don't see why any Windows program couldn't.

Comment: @AmirRachum Nice idea, but I don't control that process.

Comment: The kernel and drivers are instrumented with WMI classes such as [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372). The [wmi](https://pypi.org/project/WMI) module makes it easy to watch for "creation" of instances. See the tutorial for an example process creation monitor. Use the `Name` and `ProcessId` fields.